# extract indexes with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file containing:

```
toto.tata0.titi=any1
toto.tata1.titi=any2
toto.tata2.titi=any2
toto.tata3.titi=any1
toto.tata4.titi=any1
toto.tata5.titi=any2
```

I want to extract all the `tata` references which equal to `any2`

How I can do it with only one command ( `sed` for example)?

I can do it with 2 commands `grep` and `cut`

```
$ cat file | grep "toto\.[^.]\+\.titi=any2" | cut -d. -f2
tata1
tata2
tata5
```

Comment: Please clarify. Is **=any2** a sufficient match, or do you have to look at other parts of the line? Is there always a **tata** term, or could it be missing? If missing, no match even if there is an "any2"? How much of a matching line do you want to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) you can search for any line that ends with `any2` and use two substitution commands, the first one to delete all characters until first `.` and the second one to delete from next `.` until the end:

```
sed -ne '/any2$/ { s/^[^.]*\.//; s/\..*$//; p }' infile
```

It yields:

```
tata1
tata2
tata5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F'=' '$2=="any2"{print $1}' file
toto.tata1.titi
toto.tata2.titi
toto.tata5.titi
```

OR if you just want middle part then:

```
awk -F'[.=]+' '$NF=="any2"{print $2}'  fff
tata1
tata2
tata5
```